# LEGO Star Wars age limits?

Tags: star-wars, afol

Want to buy my boyfriend LEGO for Christmas as I know he'd love it, but am very confused about the age limits on the boxes! If I buy one age 8-14 for example, is it too simple? Don't want to offend him either as he's 20 :P 
Recommendations of sets would also be appreciated!

Comment: Sets with more pieces or a higher age range will be more challenging.  If he's into Star Wars he'll probably be excited to get any of them.  http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1317/6174 explains a bit more in general about choosing sets.

Comment: See also [Why does LEGO have a maximum age limit](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/682/56)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a guy who's 20 you can ignore the age limits. LEGO used to label set with "N..99" age limits but these days that sort of humour is less appreciated. It's still true, though.

I suggest focus more on what he's interested in, and what you think he'd enjoy building. Within the [LEGO Star Wars](http://www.lego.com/en-us/starwars) range there are quite a lot of options. If he's mostly into collecting toys I suggest starting small, but if he's into spending hours building stuff there are options that go right up to metre-long display models.

I think your main risk is social or financial. Even if you misjudge his interest, if he's into Star Wars he's likely to build it, display it, and just not ever get round to buying more. But especially the first time, don't spend more than you're willing to have him go "what? No" at, and maybe be careful about where he opens the gift. If he has judgey relatives who might say "hahaha kids toys grow up" or similar, try to avoid. It's all obvious, but many [AFOLs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFOL) have had experiences like that.

That said, I've given LEGO for work "secret santa" events as well as other random times, and it's usually gone down well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, LEGO sets are for all ages, but star wars are usually for teenagers and up, so it's all right to get him any star wars set!